# Run a Button Code On Page Load

Tags: asp.net, openid, pageload

I Have folowing Button code and setting to take user to google for login using openid.Through this code i have to click on the button to take user to google.But I want to take user to google on page load also.Can anyone tell me how can i run the folowing command on page load event of login.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLoginToGoogle" Runat="server" Text="Login" OnCommand="OpenLogin_Click"  
                    CommandArgument="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Width="162px" 
                onclick="btnLoginToGoogle_Click" Font-Names="Arial" Height="39px" BackColor="#4C8FFD" ForeColor="White"
```

Comment: Is the action of taking the user to Google OpenID pure javascript? You can call get it running with <body onload=....> or with jQuery .ready(). Otherwise, you can call the ".click()" method of the button via Javascript.

Comment: No Brother nothing happening in JS Only C# code is behind the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("btnLoginToGoogle").click();
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question under another account, accept the answer, and then thank yourself?

Comment: U R thinking that i am tryinf to increase my repu by myself then u r thinking wrong.becuase if i have to do this then i dnt keep the name of both accounts as same but use a different name. i know the Adeel Aslam is user on stack and my name is also adeel aslam.Its a natural case of names similarity not my nature

Comment: If u are conflicting then i am going to rename my current account

Comment: @AdeelAslam think your forgetting that the user id is shown when you hover over the link, we can see your the same user...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
btnLoginToGoogle_Click(this, new EventArgs());
```

Inside the event you can extract the argument by:

```
string s = btnLoginToGoogle.CommandArgument;
```